# Jquery and get value based on class name

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, taxonomy

I have one html tag where I would like to get the value

```
<INPUT id=ctl00_MyTaxonomyFieldID_ctl00_ctl01 class="ms-taxonomy ms-taxonomy-height ms-long" value=MyTaxonomyFieldValue|f0d123d1-ac8c-4a18-bccb-65c9b5ea83af type=hidden>
```

The result should be like f0d123d1-ac8c-4a18-bccb-65c9b5ea83af

Thanks.

Comment: use regular expressions

Comment: var x = $('ms-taxonomy ms-taxonomy-height ms-long').text('value').html();

Comment: I m not very good at Jquery guys

Comment: @Mr.coder - that's not good advice for something as simple as this. OP: I think it would be beneficial for you to [learn basic jquery](http://learn.jquery.com) and also search for the individual parts of your problem using google e.g. 'get element value jquery', 'split string javascript', 'get last array element javascript'. A combination of those three searches will give you a solution and you'll learn much more than if the answer was just posted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE[2]:**

To call by full class name use:

```
$('.ms-taxonomy.ms-taxonomy-height.ms-long').val().split('|')[1]
```

To call more than one class name, you must separate them using `'.'`

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZXRTP/2/

**UPDATE:**

To get it based on class name, use:

```
$('.ms-taxonomy').val().split('|')[1]
```

Where `'.ms-taxonomy'` is the class name you want to call.
To call an ID you must use `#IDvalue`, to call a class use `.CLASSvalue`

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZXRTP/1/

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

Use `""` to open and close yout attributes appropriately.

```
<input id="ctl00_MyTaxonomyFieldID_ctl00_ctl01" class="ms-taxonomy ms-taxonomy-height ms-long" value="MyTaxonomyFieldValue|f0d123d1-ac8c-4a18-bccb-65c9b5ea83af" type="hidden">
```

First we need to understand you rules. If every input valu starts with `"MyTaxonomyFieldValue|"`, then you can use this:

```
$('#ctl00_MyTaxonomyFieldID_ctl00_ctl01').val().split('|')[1]
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZXRTP/

Comment: wait a minute, in case I wanna get it based on class name then ?

Comment: @user3674148 - if you had checked the link I posted you would have already seen this page: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/

Comment: @Joe: yep - I m trying ;)

Comment: @LGVentura - when I pass the full class name as in .ms-taxonomy ms-taxonomy-height ms-long - it is not firing - any clue ??